# What's the most lightweight way to have two .net apps talk to each other?

Tags: .net, ipc

We have a .net service with simple commands (play, pause, next track, for example). This is installed on users' workstation's with its own credentials (FooServiceUser, for example). If I want to give the users an app that can send the commands to the service, what would be the most lightweight way to do so?  Remember I only want to send commands from a single workstation to a process running on that same workstation. The commands are very simple. Also the app needs to receive status from the service. ie paused, playing track 21.

Should be easy right? WCF looks complicated and overkill. Everyone on SO is saying .net remoting is bad. I don't want to install MSMQ. Every mention of sockets gets a negative score.

Comment: What 'weight' are you looking to keep 'light'? Size of deployment payload? LOC? Learning curve?

Comment: Light means, easy to learn, understand, and have little in the way of going wrong. I'm transitioning from c++ win32. So the equivilent of named pipes is what I was looking for. Instead I see whole books worth of extra stuff, tons of information on technologies I probably don't need.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to also add, low on memory footprint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a complete, easy to use solution I would recommend WCF. It supports a memory-channel protocol (ICP) for just this application.

Remains what you would call 'light-weight'. The hosting part of WCF can be accomplished in about 5 lines of code. All client-side code is generated. So do you really care about the number and size of the assemblies you have to use (already installed) or the amount of features you're going to ignore?

Just use WCF.
And it will let you easily scale out to sockets and inter-PC if the need ever arises.

Comment: "The hosting part of WCF can be accomplished in about 5 lines of code" that does not translate lightweight.

Comment: @aliosta, maybe, but what does?

Comment: @aliosta, remoting wouldn't qualify as 'light' in the learning dept. And I really don't see where else it does. WCF is part of the Client profile, right?

Comment: I think he meant in terms of performance and hardware requirements.

Comment: And I don't think (can't imagine) the hardware reqs being any higher.

Comment: TCP is not supported! I actually knew it from my personal experience that it didnt work with client profile.

Comment: @aliostad That's not how I read that page. Anyway, the OP wants IPC

Answer (score 6):

I would have absolutely said Remoting is superseded and use WCF with named pipe binding but now that you are talking about **lightweightness**, I must say Remoting is lightweight and is not going anywhere since communication between two AppDomains are usually by remoting. So it is indeed a **valid** choice.

Having said that, considering the *flexibility* of WCF, I would still recommend - although it is *heavy, chunky and way overcooked*.

Comment: I would say Remoting has been assimilated (Borg style) into WCF, are you really advocating the use of an outdated technology? What exactly would be the 'lightweight' advantages?

Comment: IpcChannel is the named pipe channel for Remoting

Comment: Abstractions built into WCF are way too heavy and overcooked. Its channel stack is filled with so much stuff. Some call WCF rich, I call it overdone.

Answer (score 2):

If the app is on the same machine as the Windows Service, you probably don't even have to worry about using remoting, web services, etc, since you can instantiate the [ServiceController Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) and use its ExecuteCommand method.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could do that... It seems quite limited though (no way to pass arguments to a command, limited number of commands...)

Comment: How does this work on a security level? The all users should be allowed to send "play" or "pause" but not stop or start the service or be allowed to affect other services.

Comment: Agreed that lack of parameters and set number of commands are overwhelming constraints in some situations, but it fits nicely into others.  Windows Services are handled by access control lists, which also secures files and directories.  The users would have to have the start and stop permissions to be able to start and stop the service, but you would want to send a command number that represents Start, Stop, Pause, etc.  The User Defined Control permission would likely be required to send it a command.

Answer (score 2):

WCF is lightweight in terms of how may lines of code do i need to get my communication done.
Its not very lightweight in terms of execution speed ans memory consumption.
WCF is very simple to use. But its extensible architecture makes it sometimes a bit hard to find the right class.

Plain socket operation is not lightweight in terms of coding effort, but lightweight in terms of runtime operation. You have absolute full control over every bit, when channels are opened or closed and stuff like that.